# Does using Parquet on S3 with EMR/Spark save bandwidth when using subset of columns?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster running Spark. In the first step the CSV files are transformed into paruqet.snappy format partitioned by `date` column, so I am left with

```
s3://my-bucket/dataset/date=2020-12-20/part-0001.parquet.snappy
s3://my-bucket/dataset/date=2020-12-20/part-0002.parquet.snappy
s3://my-bucket/dataset/date=2020-12-20/part-0003.parquet.snappy
s3://my-bucket/dataset/date=2020-12-20/part-0004.parquet.snappy
```

the columns are

```
id,name,value
```

A subsequent job processes this data:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('s3://my-bucket/dataset')
df.registerAsTempView('dataset')
spark.sql('''
select id, 
       sum(value)
from dataset
where date=2020-12-20
group by 1;
''')
```

so in the query I am not using the `name` column. From what I understood about Parquet, the chunks of data corresponding to the column `name` wouldn't be read from disk at all.

Question:

A) Are all the `part-000x` parts of the dataset actually downloaded from S3 to the Spark cluster, but only the required columns are loaded into memory (no bandwidth is saved, but there is still the benefit of the columnar format when reading columns to memory)
or
B) Spark can somehow `seek()` into the files on S3 so that it can only download certain subsections of the parts that correspond to the required columns? (bandwith is saved)

Comment: with parquet format & High Level APIs like Dataset and DataFrame, Spark can do predicate pushdown and projection pushdown which will help in reduce the amount of data which has to be loaded into memory from disk/s3, you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235076/what-is-the-difference-between-predicate-pushdown-and-projection-pushdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to optimise object store reads for columnar data is a very interesting problem.

I can't speak for the EMR S3 connector, as I haven't seen its code.

But the general read plan of a parquet file on s3 through spark is

- file is opened (HEAD. maybe GET)
- seek to a few bytes off EOF, read magic file type (safety check) and location of full footer
- seek and read footer to say where columns are in file, schema, etc.

Then it does the work with: seek/bulk read of stripes with the columns it wants to query/include.

Exactly which APIs is used depends on library; parquet.jar does readFully(offset) with a block size of 2MB. Back-to-back reads of 2MB blocks are pretty common.

If there's any predicate pushdown, then the stripe summary data after the stripe is read, then either the stripe is skipped, or it is needed, in which case there's a backwards seek/full read of the stripe.

When working with any of the object stores, while bandwidth is limited, dealing with seek "optimally" is actually the things which keeps people busy. Do a full GET from 0-EOF and as soon as the parquet code does a seek() you have to decide whether to read and discard the remaining bytes in the request, or abort the HTTPS connection, GET a new one starting at the new position and take the hit of the cost of a new TLS negotiation.

Random IO seek policies say "do shorter GETs so we can recycle the connection for the next block"; works best for Parquet and ORC, awful for .csv, .avro etc. Then there's "do you want to do a GET of range + "extra", because of those common back-to-back reads. Or even: should you prefetch the next block?

The general consensus in the latest ASF connectors (S3A for S3 and ABFS for Azure Storage is: start off sequential and switch to random IO on the first backwards seek; add a way to change that default. ABFS also does some async prefetching of the next block, which can boost sequential reads and, if not needed, is not too expensive in terms of CPU, network and Azure billing costs.

Oh, and sometimes code does a seek(l1), seek(l2) a few times back to back, so you just remember that offset and only worry about issuing GET requests on the first read().

Like I said: it's complicated. Lots of opportunities to tune things.

*If you are using the s3a:// connector, then call .toString() on it and you get the stats on how much data has been read, skipped, discarded, connections aborted, etc etc.*

Further reading: [s3a connector input stream seek code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AInputStream.java#L273)